# print files that are PNG and numbers from 0-100000 in all folders

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have a directory of images, that we are processing and I want to delete all PNG images.

I want to delete only files that are like these:

```
/8k/8095/p_149554/420_1527072930.png
./8k/8095/p_1453/1000_1527072907.png
./8k/8095/p_153/80_1527072907.png
./8k/8095/p_149553/260_1527072907.png
./8k/8095/p_149553/new_origin.png
./8k/8095/p_149553/340_1527072907.png
./8k/8095/p_149553/150_1527072907.png
./8k/8095/p_149553/main.png
./8k/8095/p_149553/420_1527072907.png
./8k/8546/p_162421/340_1530296168.png
./8k/8546/p_162421/150_1530296168.png
./8k/8546/p_162421/main.png
./8k/8546/p_162421/260_1530296168.png
./8k/8546/p_162421/420_1530296168.png
./8k/8546/p_162421/80_1530296168.png
./8k/8546/p_162421/1000_1530296168.png
./8k/8546/p_162419/1000_1530296127.png
./8k/8546/p_162419/260_1530296127.png
./8k/8546/p_162419/80_1530296127.png
./8k/8546/p_62419/340_1530296127.png
./8k/8546/p_62419/150_1530296127.png
./8k/8546/p_62419/main.png
./8k/8546/p_62419/420_1530296127.png
```

I need to remove all the png files that are in a subfolder os the ones that have p_(<100000) or between 1-100000

Thanks

Comment: Could you be clearer please? You have given three different criteria. You said *"all PNGs"*, *"all PNGs below 100,000"* and *"all PNGs 1-100,000"*.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Print files (headline) or remove files?

Comment: Print will be good start .. i can adjust later to delete

I want 1-100000

Answer (score 1):

Use regex with `find`:

```sh
find . -type f -regextype egrep -iregex '.*/p_1?[[:digit:]]{0,5}/.*\.png' -print
```

If the output matches the files to be deleted, then replace `-print` by `-delete`

See the regex detailed here: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZvALpg/3)

Comment: I think *the ones that have p_(<100000)* means *excluding 100000*

Comment: @oguzismail poster wrote: "p_(<100000) **or between 1-100000**" so this also include 100000. And this also correlates to the sample matches from his post.

Comment: That statement doesn't even make sense to me. But upvoted anyways, as this is the most reasonable approach

Answer (score 0):

Would yo please try the following:

```
while IFS= read -r -d "" f; do
    dir="${f%/*}"                               # extract the directory portion
    n="${dir/*\/p_/}"                           # extract the number after "p_"
    if (( n > 1 && n < 100000 )); then          # if the number is between 1 and 100,000
        echo "$f"
        # rm -- "$f"                            # uncomment if the result is ok
    fi
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.png" -print0)  # feed the result of "find" to the "while" loop
```

If your definition of `between` is `inclusive`, replace the `>` sign with `>=`
and `<` with `<=`.